# Change span text when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I'm creating a social media page, and I am adding functionality where if a posts characters are greater than 50, show a shorter version, and append a "*...more*" at the end.

In my models.py, I have a function that displays 50 characters and beyond, and I want to use this when the "*...more*" is pressed.

Currently, when pressed, the text just completely disappears.

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=600)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def pub_date_pretty(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')

    def summary_pretty(self):
        return self.summary[:50]

    def summary_rem(self):
        return self.summary[50:]
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'accounts/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load static %}
{% for post in posts %}
  <div class="container pl-5">
    <div class="row pt-3">
      <img src="{% static 'rect.jpg' %}" width="600px" height="60px">
      <div class="pt-3 pl-5" style="position: absolute;"> <b> {{ post.user.username }} </b> </div>
      <br>
      <div class="card" style="width: 600px;">
         <img src="{{ post.file.url }}" width="599px">
      </div>
      <br>
      <img src="{% static 'rect.jpg' %}" width="600px" height="150px">
      <div class="col-6">
        <script>
           function addMore(e) {
              e.innerText = "{{ post.summary_rem }}";
            }
        </script>
          {% if post.summary|length > 50 %}
              <div class="" style="position: absolute; bottom: 75px; left: 35px;"> <b> {{ post.user.username }} </b> {{ post.summary_pretty }} <span onclick="addMore(this)" style="cursor: pointer;" class="text-muted">...more</span> </div>
          {% else %}
              <div class="" style="position: absolute; bottom: 75px; left: 35px;"> <b> {{ post.user.username }} </b> {{ post.summary }}  </div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

added:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function addMore(e) {
      e.innerText = "{{ post.summary_rem }}";
    }
</script>
  {% if post.summary|length > 50 %}
      <div class="" style="position: absolute; bottom: 75px; left: 35px;"> <b> {{ post.user.username }} </b> {{ post.summary_pretty }} <span  onclick="addMore(this)" style="cursor: pointer;" class="text-muted">...more</span> </div>
  {% else %}
      <div class="" style="position: absolute; bottom: 75px; left: 35px;"> <b> {{ post.user.username }} </b> {{ post.summary }}  </div>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: What text disappears completely? Can you check in your browser dev tools that the text that needs to be added is shown in the `addMore` function? Set a breakpoint in your browser on the line `e.innerText` and check the value of `e` when clicking.

Comment: Ok, and the text within <span> (...more) disappears

Comment: so "...more" is replaced by nothing? The preceding short summary stays? Look at the source in your dev tools to see the html. is the <span> just empty after you click it?

Comment: Yes the "...more" text is replaced with an empty string. And the short summary does stay

Comment: And I have checked the dev tools, and yes the <span> tag is empty when I click it.

Comment: and what does the line `e.innerText = ` say?

Comment: It shows the correct text that I want to display, (post.summary_rem), however the span tag is empty.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with django python. It is purely javascript problem.

Comment: Oh right. Do you know what the problem is.

Comment: Do you want to replace the text when more button is clicked?

Comment: yes, that is my aim.

Comment: The e.innerText says the correct text, as I checked in dev tools. However the span text doesn't get replaced when it is expected to.

Comment: I can't reproduce the text being empty, it just works for me when I copy & paste your code in a page. Does the string that's in the place of post.summary_rem contain HTML tags? Can you set a breakpoint inside your addMore function and check what's going on? Do you see javascript errors in your console? Try the same with a fixed string like "testing addMore" instead of "{{ post.summary_rem }}". Check the css for your <span>.

Comment: I have replaced the post.summary_rem with a fixed string, and it works perfectly as expected. I have also checked for javascript errors in the console, and there isn't any. However when post.summary_rem is replaced with a fixed string everything works.

Comment: show us the actual html source code for that line (copy & paste from your 'show source' in your browser). You say it's showing what you expect, but apparently it's not since it works with a fixed string.

Comment: Look at original post.